# Itextpdf cuts down content in new page when fails loading img

Tags: java, itext

I'm passing an HTML document to itextpdf that takes 2 pages. At the beginning of the document there is a logo of the company, then some tables and at the end, the logo of the client company of the first company. Both logos `<img>` are inside tables. Don't know why. Was already set this way.

When the path of the images are found everything works just fine. But when the first image is not found I get no second page. If the second image is not found everything is OK.

The funny thing is that if I add a tag with text inside before or after the table of the second image it works OK no matter if both images are not found.

I'm fixing bugs for a company so the whole flow for this system I'm working on is already set up. The software reads an HTML document into a string in java. And then print it using itextpdf.

This is the HTML code that is read from the file "test2.html" which serves as a template.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <title>#Title</title>
      <style>
         html, body {
         padding:0;
         margin:0;
         }
         @page {
         size:4in 11in;
         }
         @media print {
         body {
         transform: scale(1.00);
         }
         @page {
         margin:2px;
         }
         }
         body {
         font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
         font-size: 10px;
         }
         .divTicketWrapper {
         margin: auto;  
         min-width: 60em;
         <!-- width:50%; -->
         }
         .scaled {
         transform: scale(0.7); /* Equal to scaleX(0.7) scaleY(0.7) */
         background-color: pink;
         }
         .divRow {
         margin-top:0.2em;
         overflow: auto;
         }
         h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
         margin:0.2em;
         }
         header {
         height:100px;
         display:block;
         }
         .headerLogo {
         float:left;
         }
         .headerInfo {
         overflow:auto;
         text-align:center;
         float:right;
         font-size: 12px;
         font-weight:bold;
         }
         article {
         }
         section {
         padding: 0.1em 0 0.1em 0;
         border:none;
         }
         .section{
         background-color:#FFCC99;
         color:#000000;
         text-align:center;
         }
         .sectionHeader {
         background-color:#FFCC99;
         color:#000000;
         text-align:center;
         }
         .divLeftColumn {   
         float:left;
         padding-right:0.2em;
         }
         .divRightColumn {
         overflow: auto;    
         float:right;
         }
         .divLabel {    
         overflow:hidden;
         float:left;
         white-space: nowrap;
         font-weight:bold;
         padding-right:0.2em;
         font-size: 10px;   
         width:20%;
         }
         .divField {
         background-color: #DDDDDD;
         white-space: nowrap;
         overflow:hidden;   
         font-size: 10px;   
         }
         .divFieldWrap {
         white-space: normal;
         max-height:4em;
         }
         .divLabelBackGround {
         background-color:#FFCC99;
         color:#000000;
         text-align:center;
         font-size:10px;
         font-weight:bold;
         height:20px;
         }
         

      </style>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="divTicketWrapper">
         <header>
            <div class="headerLogo"><img src="T:/orgs/images/logo.png" alt="logo" width="130" height="100" style="width:130px; height:100px;" ></img></div>
            <div class="headerInfo">
               <div style="font-size:18px; font-weight:bold;"> TRANSPORT, LLC</div>
               <div>SOUTH US</div>
               <div>US, 123344</div>
               <div>EMERGENCY CONTACT: 12345667</div>
            </div>
         </header>
         <div style="height:10px"></div>
         <!-- LOAD INFORMATION -->
         <section>
          <div  style="text-align:center;color:red"><h3></h3></div>
            <div class="sectionHeader" width="100%">
               <h3 style="font-size:10px;"> INFORMATION</h3>
            </div>
            <table width="100%">
               <tr width="100%">
                  <td class="divLabel">Product Type:</td>
                  <td class="divField"  colspan="3"> product 1</td>
               </tr>
               <tr width="100%">
                  <td class="divLeftColumn divLabel">BOL #:</td>
                  <td class="divLeftColumn divField">1234556</td>
                  <td class="divRightColumn divLabel">Trucked By:</td>
                  <td class="divRightColumn divField"> TRANSPORT, LLC</td>
               </tr>
               <tr width="100%">
                  <td class="divLeftColumn divLabel">Ticket #:</td>
                  <td class="divLeftColumn divField">123243355</td>
                  <td class="divRightColumn divLabel">Accepted Date/Time:</td>
                  <td class="divRightColumn divField">04/28/2000 22:07</td>
               </tr>
               <tr width="100%">
                  <td class="divLeftColumn divLabel">Split Ticket # w/ #:</td>
                  <td class="divLeftColumn divField"></td>
                  <td class="divRightColumn divLabel">Confirmation #:</td>
                  <td class="divRightColumn divField">1233223423</td>
               </tr>
               <!-- DROP OFF TICKET NUMBER -->
               
               <tr width="100%">
                  <td class="divLeftColumn divLabel"> Receipt #:</td>
                  <td class="divLeftColumn divField"></td>
                  <td class="divRightColumn divLabel">DO Receipt  #:</td>
                  <td class="divRightColumn divField"></td>
               </tr>
            </table>
         </section>
         
         <section>
            <div class="sectionHeader" width="100%">
               <h3 style="font-size:10px;">INFORMATION</h3>
            </div>
            <table width="100%">
               <tr width="100%">
                  <td class="divLabel">INFORMATION:</td>
                  <td class="divField" colspan="3">TRANSPORT LLC</td>
               </tr>
               <tr width="100%">
                  <td class="divLabel"> Name:</td>
                  <td class="divField" colspan="3">TRANSPORT A 2,3,4</td>
               </tr>
        
               <tr width="100%">
                  <td class="divLabel">Operator:</td>
                  <td class="divField" colspan="3">TRANSPORT</td>
               </tr>
               <tr width="100%">
                  <td class="divLeftColumn divLabel">PickUp #:</td>
                  <td class="divLeftColumn divField">TRANSPORT</td>
                  <td class="divRightColumn divLabel">Arrival Date &amp; Time::</td>
                  <td class="divRightColumn divField">04/28/2000 22:39</td>
               </tr>
               <tr width="100%">
                  <td class="divLeftColumn divLabel">PickUp #:</td>
                  <td class="divLeftColumn divField"></td>
                  <td class="divRightColumn divLabel">Load Time:</td>
                  <td class="divRightColumn divField">00:08</td>
               </tr>
               <tr width="100%">
                  <td class="divLeftColumn divLabel">Legal Description:</td>
                  <td class="divLeftColumn divField"></td>
                  <td class="divRightColumn divLabel">Wait Time:</td>
                  <td class="divRightColumn divField">00:00</td>
               </tr>
               <tr width="100%">
                  <td class="divLeftColumn divLabel">Latitude:</td>
                  <td class="divLeftColumn divField">1212324343</td>
                  <td class="divRightColumn divLabel">Pickup Date &amp; Time:</td>
                  <td class="divRightColumn divField">04/28/2000 22:47</td>
               </tr>
               <tr width="100%">
                  <td class="divLeftColumn divLabel">Longitude:</td>
                  <td class="divLeftColumn divField">123322344</td>
                  <td class="divRightColumn divLabel">Loaded Miles:</td>
                  <td class="divRightColumn divField">100</td>
               </tr>
               <tr width="100%">
                  <td class="divLabel">County, State::</td>
                  <td class="divField" colspan="3">TRANSPORT</td>
               </tr>
               <tr width="100%">
                  <td class="divLabel">Wait Time Notes:</td>
                  <td class="divField" colspan="3"></td>
               </tr>
               <tr width="100%">
                  <td class="divLabel">Reject Notes:</td>
                  <td class="divField" colspan="3"></td>
               </tr>
               <tr width="100%">
                  <td class="divLabel">Other Notes:</td>
                  <td class="divField" colspan="3">Tank In Production;</td>
               </tr>
            </table>
         </section>
 <section> <div class="sectionHeader"  width="100%"><h3 style="font-size:10px;">PICK UP</h3></div><table width="100%"> <tr><td class="divLeftColumn divLabel">TRANSPORT</td> <td class="divLeftColumn divField divFieldWrap">ACCEPT</td> <td class="divRightColumn divLabel">TRANSPORT</td> <td class="divRightColumn divField divFieldWrap"></td> </tr><tr><td class="divLeftColumn divLabel">TRANSPORT Type</td> <td class="divLeftColumn divField divFieldWrap">TRANSPORT</td> <td class="divRightColumn divLabel">BS&amp;W(%)</td> <td class="divRightColumn divField divFieldWrap">0.1</td> </tr><tr><td class="divLeftColumn divLabel">TRANSPORT</td> <td class="divLeftColumn divField divFieldWrap">TRANSPORT</td> <td class="divRightColumn divLabel">TRANSPORT</td> <td class="divRightColumn divField divFieldWrap">90.0</td> </tr><tr><td class="divLeftColumn divLabel">TRANSPORT</td> <td class="divLeftColumn divField divFieldWrap">0.0</td> <td class="divRightColumn divLabel">TRANSPORT</td> <td class="divRightColumn divField divFieldWrap">90.0</td> </tr><tr><td class="divLeftColumn divLabel">TRANSPORT</td> <td class="divLeftColumn divField divFieldWrap">0.01</td> <td class="divRightColumn divLabel">TRANSPORT</td> <td class="divRightColumn divField divFieldWrap">90.0</td> </tr><tr><td class="divLeftColumn divLabel">TRANSPORT</td> <td class="divLeftColumn divField divFieldWrap">0 ft 0 in 0 in <br></br>(0.0 in)</td> <td class="divRightColumn divLabel">TRANSPORT</td> <td class="divRightColumn divField divFieldWrap">53.0</td> </tr><tr><td class="divLeftColumn divLabel">TRANSPORT</td> <td class="divLeftColumn divField divFieldWrap">0 ft 0 in 0 in <br></br>(0.0 in)</td> <td class="divRightColumn divLabel">TRANSPORT</td> <td class="divRightColumn divField divFieldWrap">49.9</td> </tr><tr><td class="divLeftColumn divLabel">TRANSPORT</td> <td class="divLeftColumn divField divFieldWrap">194.0</td> <td class="divRightColumn divLabel">TRANSPORT</td> <td class="divRightColumn divField divFieldWrap">TRANSPORT</td> </tr><tr><td class="divLeftColumn divLabel">TRANSPORT</td> <td class="divLeftColumn divField divFieldWrap">190.53</td> <td class="divRightColumn divLabel">TRANSPORT</td> <td class="divRightColumn divField divFieldWrap">04/28/2000 22:39</td> </tr><tr><td class="divLeftColumn divLabel">TRANSPORT</td> <td class="divLeftColumn divField divFieldWrap">190.72</td> <td class="divRightColumn divLabel">TRANSPORT</td> <td class="divRightColumn divField divFieldWrap">121313</td> </tr><tr><td class="divLeftColumn divLabel">TRANSPORT</td> <td class="divLeftColumn divField divFieldWrap">0 ft 0 in 0 in <br></br>(0.0 in)</td> <td class="divRightColumn divLabel">TRANSPORT</td> <td class="divRightColumn divField divFieldWrap">04/28/2000 22:47</td> </tr> </table> </section>
         <!-- / PICKUP INFORMATION -->
         <section> <div class="sectionHeader"  width="100%"><h3 style="font-size:10px;">PICK UP</h3></div><table width="100%"> <tr><td class="divLeftColumn divLabel">TRANSPORT</td> <td class="divLeftColumn divField divFieldWrap">ACCEPT</td> <td class="divRightColumn divLabel">Reject Reason</td> <td class="divRightColumn divField divFieldWrap"></td> </tr><tr><td class="divLeftColumn divLabel">TRANSPORT</td> <td class="divLeftColumn divField divFieldWrap">TRANSPORT</td> <td class="divRightColumn divLabel">BS&amp;W(%)</td> <td class="divRightColumn divField divFieldWrap">0.1</td> </tr><tr><td class="divLeftColumn divLabel">TRANSPORT</td> <td class="divLeftColumn divField divFieldWrap">TRANSPORT</td> <td class="divRightColumn divLabel">TRANSPORT</td> <td class="divRightColumn divField divFieldWrap">90.0</td> </tr><tr><td class="divLeftColumn divLabel">TRANSPORT</td> <td class="divLeftColumn divField divFieldWrap">0.0</td> <td class="divRightColumn divLabel">TRANSPORT</td> <td class="divRightColumn divField divFieldWrap">90.0</td> </tr><tr><td class="divLeftColumn divLabel">TRANSPORT</td> <td class="divLeftColumn divField divFieldWrap">0.01</td> <td class="divRightColumn divLabel">TRANSPORT</td> <td class="divRightColumn divField divFieldWrap">90.0</td> </tr><tr><td class="divLeftColumn divLabel">TRANSPORT</td> <td class="divLeftColumn divField divFieldWrap">0 ft 0 in 0 in <br></br>(0.0 in)</td> <td class="divRightColumn divLabel">TRANSPORT</td> <td class="divRightColumn divField divFieldWrap">53.0</td> </tr><tr><td class="divLeftColumn divLabel">TRANSPORT</td> <td class="divLeftColumn divField divFieldWrap">0 ft 0 in 0 in <br></br>(0.0 in)</td> <td class="divRightColumn divLabel">TRANSPORT</td> <td class="divRightColumn divField divFieldWrap">49.9</td> </tr><tr><td class="divLeftColumn divLabel">TRANSPORT</td> <td class="divLeftColumn divField divFieldWrap">194.0</td> <td class="divRightColumn divLabel">TRANSPORT</td> <td class="divRightColumn divField divFieldWrap">TRANSPORT</td> </tr><tr><td class="divLeftColumn divLabel">TRANSPORT</td> <td class="divLeftColumn divField divFieldWrap">190.53</td> <td class="divRightColumn divLabel">TRANSPORT</td> <td class="divRightColumn divField divFieldWrap">04/28/2000 22:39</td> </tr><tr><td class="divLeftColumn divLabel">TRANSPORT</td> <td class="divLeftColumn divField divFieldWrap">190.72</td> <td class="divRightColumn divLabel">TRANSPORT</td> <td class="divRightColumn divField divFieldWrap">108712121215</td> </tr><tr><td class="divLeftColumn divLabel">TRANSPORT</td> <td class="divLeftColumn divField divFieldWrap">0 ft 0 in 0 in <br></br>(0.0 in)</td> <td class="divRightColumn divLabel">TRANSPORT</td> <td class="divRightColumn divField divFieldWrap">04/28/2000 22:47</td> </tr> </table> </section>
         <!-- DROPOFF INFORMATION -->
         <section class="">
            <div class="sectionHeader" width="100%">
               <h3 style="font-size:10px;">TRANSPORT</h3>
            </div>
            <table width="100%">
               <tr width="100%">
                  <td class="divLabel">TRANSPORT:</td>
                  <td class="divField" colspan="3"></td>
               </tr>
               <tr width="100%">
                  <td class="divLabel">TRANSPORT:</td>
                  <td class="divField" colspan="3"></td>
               </tr>
        
               <tr width="100%">
                  <td class="divLeftColumn divLabel">TRANSPORT:</td>
                  <td class="divLeftColumn divField"></td>
                  <td class="divRightColumn divLabel">Arrival Date &amp; Time:</td>
                  <td class="divRightColumn divField"></td>
               </tr>
               <tr width="100%">
                  <td class="divLeftColumn divLabel">TRANSPORT #:</td>
                  <td class="divLeftColumn divField"></td>
                  <td class="divRightColumn divLabel">TRANSPORT:</td>
                  <td class="divRightColumn divField"></td>
               </tr>
               <tr width="100%">
                  <td class="divLeftColumn divLabel">Latitude:</td>
                  <td class="divLeftColumn divField"></td>
                  <td class="divRightColumn divLabel">Wait Time:</td>
                  <td class="divRightColumn divField"></td>
               </tr>
               <tr width="100%">
                  <td class="divLeftColumn divLabel">Longitude:</td>
                  <td class="divLeftColumn divField"></td>
                  <td class="divRightColumn divLabel">DropOff Date &amp; Time:</td>
                  <td class="divRightColumn divField"></td>
               </tr>
               <tr width="100%">
                  <td class="divLabel">TRANSPORT</td>
                  <td class="divField" colspan="3">TRANSPORT</td>
               </tr>
               <tr width="100%">
                  <td class="divLabel">Wait Time Notes:</td>
                  <td class="divField" colspan="3"></td>
               </tr>
               <tr width="100%">
                  <td class="divLabel">Other Notes:</td>
                  <td class="divField" colspan="3"></td>
               </tr>
            </table>
         </section>                  <section class="">
      
         </section>
         <!-- / DROPOFF INFORMATION -->
         <section class="">
            
         </section>
         <!-- DRIVER PICKUP &amp; DROPOFF -->
         <section class="">
         
            <div class="">
               <table width="100%" style="border-collapse: collapse;">
                  <tr width="100%">
                     <td class="divLeftColumn divLabel divLabelBackGround">TRANSPORT</td>
                     <td class="divRightColumn divLabel divLabelBackGround">TRANSPORT</td>
                  </tr>
               </table>
               <table width="100%">
                  <tr width="100%">
                     <td class="divLeftColumn divLabel">TRANSPORT #:</td>
                     <td class="divLeftColumn divField">100</td>
                     <td class="divRightColumn divLabel">TRANSPORT #:</td>
                     <td class="divRightColumn divField"></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr width="100%">
                     <td class="divLeftColumn divLabel">TRANSPORT #:</td>
                     <td class="divLeftColumn divField">1015</td>
                     <td class="divRightColumn divLabel">TRANSPORT #:</td>
                     <td class="divRightColumn divField"></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr width="100%">
                     <td class="divLeftColumn divLabel">TRANSPORT:</td>
                     <td class="divLeftColumn divField">TRANSPORT</td>
                     <td class="divRightColumn divLabel">TRANSPORT:</td>
                     <td class="divRightColumn divField"></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr width="100%">
                     <td class="divLeftColumn divLabel">TRANSPORT:</td>
                     <td class="divLeftColumn divField">102</td>
                     <td class="divRightColumn divLabel">TRANSPORT:</td>
                     <td class="divRightColumn divField"></td>
                  </tr>
               </table>
            </div>
            
            </section>
            <p>hola</p>
         <table width="100%" style="border-collapse: collapse;">
            <tr width="100%">
               <td  style="text-align:center;"><img src="T:/orgs/images/logo.png" alt="logo" width="74" height="20" style="width:74px; height:20px;" /></td>
            </tr>
         </table>
         
         <span style= "page-break-after: always;"></span>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

This is the "main.java" I created so you can run the code. This reads the "test2.html" from "C:\temp" and generates a pdf of 4x11 inches.

```java
String tempFolder ="C:\temp\";
        String fileName="test2.html";
        String pdfFileName = Utils.generateRandomString();
        pdfFileName += ".pdf";
        final int xInch = 4;
        final int yInch = 11;
        int urx = 72* xInch; // upper right x
        int ury = 72* yInch; // upper right y
        Rectangle rectangle=new Rectangle(urx, ury);

        Document document = new Document(rectangle);
        document.setMargins(10,10,10,10);
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(tempFolder + "/" + pdfFileName));

        document.open();
        XMLWorkerHelper.getInstance().parseXHtml(writer, document, new FileInputStream(tempFolder + "/" + fileName));
        document.close();
```

Guys this code is ugly as hell but is not mine. Its a horrible software my company bought and now I need to fix all the crap introducing as minimal changes as possible. Of course all the info in the html was changed to dummy data because I can't post real info here, but this code presents the problem very accurately

I never created PDFs before from code.
itextpdf is 5.5.13

Comment: Code is really needed in this case to answer your question. Try to reduce your code to as minimal as possible that still reproduces the problem. Someone reading your question should be able to copy/paste your code and be able to run it without making any changes. That means: no images of your code. Also, which version of iText? At the very least, we need to know iText 7.x.x or iText 5.x.x.

Comment: In addition to @Amedee's hints please be aware that this may be a case of garbage in - garbage out.